# Windows 7 Service Pack 1 with NTFS Junctions: ERROR_NOT_SAME_DEVICE(0x80070011)

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, service-pack, junction

I have a quick question about installing Windows 7 Service Pack 1 with NTFS Junctions in place. I keep getting this error: ERROR_NOT_SAME_DEVICE(0x80070011).

Now from what I researched online it is because of the NTFS Junctions of Program Files, Program Files (x86), and Users hard links are broken.

Link to forum I used(I know it's for Vista):
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasp/thread/a2a6876d-eb2e-4238-98a9-4933ad5da996/

Is there a way I can install the SP1 with a Windows 7 boot disk? I really don't want to re-install Windows 7. So is there a way I can get away with installing the Service Pack 1 while keeping the NTFS Junctions in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is **not possible**. Windows doesn't like having replaced important folders like program Files with junctions.

Comment: I thought so. In the end I am just going to reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's quite a long time ago the OP asked this question, but I was searching for the answer, and this came out as a primary source. I've refused to bow down to a **NO** answer above, and I've **found a solution** (at least it worked for me).

You need to temporarily change paths in these registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

Usually the errors were caused by Windows Updates, feature installations, and some Microsoft software installations. Example for C: and D: drives:

```
 1. store the original registry key values 
 2. change listed registry key values from C: or %SystemDrive% to D: (your alternate path)
 3. perform update, feature installation, or whatever (never restart computer before doing step 5) 
 4. either it succeeds (you're lucky), or fails (never happened to me, but it's possible)   
 5. restore the registry key values to point back to C: (or other system drive) junctions
```

**Optimization:**

I've made myself the exported *.reg file with original values, and also one with the modified values. That way I can quickly switch between those two, update, return values back.

**Note:**

If you don't listen to my warnings, leave the modified values, and then restart a computer. All the shortcuts will be invalid, and possibly much worse things may happen. But I was able to boot normally. So it's not that destructive.

This advice worked for me, and is given with in good faith, but I'm not responsible for any harm it may possibly cause to your system. Nothing bad happened to me though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried offline installation?

Download

Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (KB976932)
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c3202ce6-4056-4059-8a1b-3a9b77cdfdda&displaylang=en

Comment: Yeah. I tried doing that,, but still with no luck.